# Installing SUDS in python 2.6.4

Tags: python, installation, easy-install, suds, setup.py

I am having real trouble installing SUDS in python 2.6.4. I have tried to install the setup file but it says the location of python cannot be found. This is because I have changed the location of python. I have tried to use easy_install but am having no luck. Does anyone know a simple way to do this or have a link to clear installation instructions.

Command that I entered was:

```
python setup.py install
```

The result I recieved was:

```
running install
error: cannot create or remove files in install directory

The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
installation directory:

    [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/test-easy-install-9203.write-test'

The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:

    /usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/

Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  If the
installation directory is a system-owned directory, you may need to sign in
as the administrator or "root" account.  If you do not have administrative
access to this machine, you may wish to choose a different installation
directory, preferably one that is listed in your PYTHONPATH environment
variable.

For information on other options, you may wish to consult the
documentation at:

  http://peak.telecommunity.com/EasyInstall.html
```

And if I have to change the python path how exactly do you do this.

I have tried what one site said to do and it was to first, create an altinstall.pth file in Python's site-packages directory, containing the following line:

```
import os, site; site.addsitedir(os.path.expanduser('~/lib/python2.3'))
```

Then it says modify distutils.cfg in the distutils directory with:

```
[install]
install_lib = ~/lib/python2.3
# This next line is optional but often quite useful; it directs EasyInstall
# and the distutils to install scripts in the user's "bin" directory.  For
# Mac OS X framework Python builds, you should use /usr/local/bin instead,
# because neither ~/bin nor the default script installation location are on
# the system PATH.
#
install_scripts = ~/bin
```

Comment: We'll need more information, like what platform you're on, exact commands tried, exact errors reported, etc.

Comment: @gruszczy Thanks, I don't know why I didn't change to superuser. I thought it was the path causing the problem. Bit silly really, thanks for the help

Comment: N/p. Remember, that if you are using easy_install, you need to be a super too. Happy hacking with suds :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried setting PYTHONPATH to the location of python? Maybe this way it will know, where to install it.

You are calling it with `python setup.py install`. Try `sudo python setup.py install`, if you are using some linux and you are sudoer.

Answer (score 1):

I got messages like this too when I installed suds and python-ntlm.  Our site has a separate areafor installations so that we can maintain multiple versions, so my first installation step was

```
python setup.py install --prefix=/install/suds/suds-0.4
```

and I got the same messages about installplace.    To fix:

Make sure the directories are there with

```
mkdir -p  /install/suds/suds-0.4/lib/python2.6/site-packages/
```

(This surprised me a little, I thought setup would build the directories.)

Make sure you have write permission down the tree with

```
chmod -R 775 /install/suds/suds-0.4/lib/python2.6/site-packages/
```

Neither of which got rid of the message!

The last step was to put the install area into PYTHONPATH, and then do the setup.py

```
export PYTHONPATH=/install/suds/suds-0.4/lib/python2.6/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH
python setup.py install --prefix=/opt/sw/fw/qce/suds/suds-0.4
```

with a final chmod to make the newly installed files readable in case umask is set to something restrictive:

```
 chmod 755 /install/suds/suds-0.4/lib/python2.6/site-packages/*
```

After this I could start python and import suds.   The key step was the putting the suds site-packages directory into PYTHONPATH.

I expect this help comes  too late to help the original poster, but I hope it helps someone else who come to SO with this question.   As I did.

Answer (score 0):

I would need more details of your OS to give a fully accurate response. From the sounds of your question, you changed your path of python. Normally you'll have a preinstalled version of python that is compatible with your OS. For example, CentOS 5.x comes with python 2.4, however you can do a `yum install` of python 2.6. Once installed, you can run python 2.6 by the `python26` command.

When doing installs and packages, I would recommend that you try to use package managers as much as possible, as they help take care of your dependencies, such as `yum`. Yum also helps control updating packages instead of having to do updates manually. The next best thing is to do installs via `pip` or `easy install`, in the case of this question, you can try `easy_install https://fedorahosted.org/releases/s/u/suds/python-suds-0.4.tar.gz` (requires setuptools), and as a last resort, you can try to do the manual install. I if I get the point that I'm doing a manual install, I feel I failed somewhere :) 
Others have given good detail on on how to do the install manually.

Good luck.